# Monitor the bluetooth traffic with wireshark on windows

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark

I need to monitor the bluetooth traffic, both inbound and outbound from my computer. Is there anyway I can do this on Windows? I've read that this is possible under linux with the `libpcap-0.9.6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be an old post but would like to answer. Currently bluetooth packet sniffing is not possible with winpcap. It is only possible with libpcap on linux.

Comment: Agreed.  I am not aware of any way to do this on Windows.  TCPDump will do it on Linux and you can use PacketLogger on macOS to see a certain degree of Bluetooth data going in and out of the machine.

Answer (score 2):

M$ has released a Bluetooth test package which includes a tool for doing exactly this, just follow the [simple instructions](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#windows-10), no special hardware required. Executing btvs.exe launches Wireshark automatically in BT capture mode - easy.

Answer (score 1):

I've would have used a packet sniffer, for example Wireshark, and see if you can find it in the list over network connections/adapters and write a filter, or just capture it all. I've dont this countless times with Wireshark, in the case of a regular ethernet card, but should be simple to do with bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to me that the bluetooth card doesnt show up in wireshark, but I managed to get the mac address for this card. Is there anyway I can specify this instead?

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by this card?, do you mean the bluetooth?, maybe you have to add your bluetooth adapter as a wireless network adapter
control panel -> Network and Internet -> add a wireless device to the network, if you use win 7, not sure though

Comment: The internal bluetooth card in my pc. The name of it is Thinkpad bluetooth 3.0